# Foreach loop table, max 2 cells then a new row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a question for my foreach loop on a table design in my mvc view.

I want my loop to output max 2 cells for each table row and if and it has data to loop out more than 2 cells it adds a new row and continues to loop out the data on the cells on that row etc..

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use tables for this.

Instead, put your content in `<div>`s with `float: left` or `display: inline-block`, and make the parent element just wide enough to hold two children.

Comment: I ran into this problem and your proposed solution worked well for me too. Just curious, is this concept something fundamental or would you classify it as a niche trick. I ask because I wouldn't have envisioned this from the fundamentals I know unless I ran into your post: could you elaborate on why this works?! Thanks and upvoted!

Answer (score 6):

Iterate over the collection in increments of two.  Check to make sure that the i+1<sup>th</sup> item is available before outputting it, outputting an empty cell instead if it isn't.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i = i + 2)
{
     <tr>
        <td>@Model[i]</td> // or @Model.ElementAt(i)
        <td>@(i+1 < Model.Count() ? Model[i+1] : "")</td> // similar
     </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at using the modulus operator (%).

Something like

```
if i%2 = 0 { new line }
```